# display unique post per category

Tags: plugins, theme-development, customization, themes

On home page i need to display few post from different categories and here are some of the issues i have

1. Any posts can belongs to any number of categories.

this is how i am planning to do it

```
$cat_args = array(
     'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC',
     'exclude' => '17,1',
     'number' => '6'
   );

 $fcategories =   get_categories($cat_args);
    foreach($fcategories as $fcategory) {
    $post_args = array(
             posts_per_page' => 1,
             'cat' => $fcategory->cat_ID
           );

   $fposts = query_posts($post_args);
 while(have_posts()) : the_post();
 get_template_part('post', 'homepage');
 endwhile;
```

but i am facing few issue in this, on the `post-homepage.php` , i have following code to get category

```
$category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID);
```

and this can pick any category assigned to the post, moreover since same posts can be associated with multiple categories, its quite possible that same posst can appear under different category.

How can i display unique posst per category, so that no 2 category have same post.
As of now i can not pass any additional parameter to `get_template_part()`

Answer (score 1):

Track your post `ID`s.

```
$cat_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'exclude' => '17,1',
  'number' => '6'
);

$fcategories = get_categories($cat_args);
$used_ids = array();
foreach($fcategories as $fcategory) {
  $post_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat' => $fcategory->cat_ID
  );
  if (!empty($used_ids)) {
    $post_args['post__not_in'] = $used_ids;
  }

  $fposts = new WP_Query($post_args);
  if ($fposts->have_posts()) {
    while($fposts->have_posts()) {
      $fposts->the_post();
      $used_ids[] = $post->ID;
      get_template_part('post', 'homepage');
    }
  }
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. There are a couple of syntax errors in your code
2. Don't use `query_posts`.

   > It should be noted that using this to **replace the main query** on a page
   >   can **increase page loading times**, in worst case scenarios **more than
   >   doubling the amount of work needed or more**. While easy to use, the
   >   function is also **prone to confusion and problems** later on. See the
   >   note further below on caveats for details.
   >
   > http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts (emphasis mine)

Comment: Tanks for the inputs.Yes i saw about code syntax as i copied and edited code for question.Thanks for giving tips about not using `query_posts`

Comment: there is one issue with the solution you provide, it seems like using `new WP_Query($post_args);` causing unwanted behavior and seems like it is fetching all posts of all eligible categories where as with the  `query_posts` its working as expected

Comment: I can't look into this right now but `query_posts` is wrong.